# Выходит ошибка при компиляции проекта на Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всем привет!
Выходит такая ошибка:

> Error     The item "Models\OrganizationUnitDepartments.cs" was specified more than once in the "Sources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by

А в OrganizationUnitDepartments.cs написано следующее:

```
public partial class OrganizationUnitDepartments
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GoodBuildings { get; set; }
    public string ColorBuildings { get; set; }

    public virtual Areas Areas { get; set; }
    public virtual OrganizationUnits OrganizationUnits { get; set; }
    public virtual Regions Regions { get; set; }
}
```

В коде везде красное...
В чем ошибка не очень понял что сказано в ошибке. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: а типа понял в чем ошибка, у меня один файл дублирован. Но в проекте не нашел вторую((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выгрузите ваш проект (это делается через контекстное меню проекта в обозревателе решения), после чего откройте его как XML-файл (это делается тоже через контекстное меню).

Там будет что-то типа такого:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Models\OrganizationUnitDepartments.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

удалите дубль и загрузите проект.

Comment: Извиняюсь, а где найти (.csproj)? Нигде не нашел типа такого <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Models\OrganizationUnitDepartments.cs" />
</ItemGroup> @Ruslan_K

Comment: @qwerty это и есть ваш проект. Найти его можно в обозревателе решений или в проводнике...

Comment: спасибо, помогли. А можете сказать из за чего было дублирование?